# r using dplyr 'gather' function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like the picture showned below in 'input'.

I try to get 1 date per row (see picture below in 'desired output'). In other word, I try to do a kind of 'transpose' for each row.

Let's stipulate that the combination 'LC' and 'Prod' is a unique key.

**Input**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

**Info:**

In my real dataset, there is some missing values in the quantity field (the colored region area). Thus, I should still be able to compute with missing values.

**My try that fails**

I have tried the following but it fails...

```
library("dplyr")
outputTest <- tbl_df(inputTest) %>%
  gather(date, value, c(inputTest$LC, inputTest$Prod))

outputTest
```

**Source:**

```
inputTest <- structure(list(LC = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("berlin", 
                                                            "munchen", "stutgart"), class = "factor"), Prod = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("(STORE1)400096", "STORE2_00154"), class = "factor"), 
               PROD_TYPE = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("STORE1", 
                                                                   "STORE2"), class = "factor"), X2015.6.29 = c(20.08, 8.91, 
                                                                                                                11.38, 15.42), X2015.7.6 = c(20.66, 8.49, 10.91, 15.57), 
               X2015.7.13 = c(19.02, 8.55, 10.89, 14.6), X2015.7.20 = c(18.6, 
                                                                        7.95, 10.58, 14.31)), .Names = c("LC", "Prod", "PROD_TYPE", 
                                                                                                         "2015.6.29", "2015.7.6", "2015.7.13", "2015.7.20"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     -4L))
```

Comment: You need `inputTest %>% tbl_df %>% gather(date, value, matches("^\\d+")
)`

Comment: Hello @akrun thanks for your suggestions but it does not work it says attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped. And it still gives me an output with all the 4 initial date columns...

Comment: Based on your dput, it is working for me.  I am using `dplyr_0.7.4` and `tidyr_0.7.2`.  Also, if you check my code, I changed from `^X` to `^\\d+` after you modified the dput

Comment: @akrun I answred to your previous answer. But you updated a answer with the 'matches' function. Now it seems to work...

Answer (score 6):

Using gather, you can specify the columns you do not want to gather with the negation operator '-' (minus sign). The key in your case is the date, the value is the value, and LC, Prod, and PROD_TYPE serve as identifiers.

```
output <- as.data.frame(inputTest) %>%
        tidyr::gather(key = Date, value = Value, -LC, -Prod, -PROD_TYPE)
```

This yields:

```
         LC           Prod PROD_TYPE      Date Value
1    berlin (STORE1)400096    STORE1 2015.6.29 20.08
2  stutgart   STORE2_00154    STORE2 2015.6.29  8.91
3    berlin   STORE2_00154    STORE2 2015.6.29 11.38
4   munchen (STORE1)400096    STORE1 2015.6.29 15.42
5    berlin (STORE1)400096    STORE1  2015.7.6 20.66
6  stutgart   STORE2_00154    STORE2  2015.7.6  8.49
7    berlin   STORE2_00154    STORE2  2015.7.6 10.91
8   munchen (STORE1)400096    STORE1  2015.7.6 15.57
9    berlin (STORE1)400096    STORE1 2015.7.13 19.02
10 stutgart   STORE2_00154    STORE2 2015.7.13  8.55
11   berlin   STORE2_00154    STORE2 2015.7.13 10.89
12  munchen (STORE1)400096    STORE1 2015.7.13 14.60
13   berlin (STORE1)400096    STORE1 2015.7.20 18.60
14 stutgart   STORE2_00154    STORE2 2015.7.20  7.95
15   berlin   STORE2_00154    STORE2 2015.7.20 10.58
16  munchen (STORE1)400096    STORE1 2015.7.20 14.31
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just want to know... Is the tidyr:: necessary. Isn't it enogh to use gather(.....) ?

Comment: If you load in tidyr using library(tidyr) then the tidyr:: is not necessary. I often include it to avoid naming collisions.

Comment: OK that make sense

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have column names that starts as non-numeric.  According to `?gather`, the `...` specifies for selection of columns by using its name.  Here, we are interested in the columns that starts with number i.e. the date columns, so we can use `matches` and specify a regex to select those columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
inputTest %>%
       tbl_df %>% 
       gather(date, value, matches("^\\d+") )
```